# Multi-column IN condition from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Oracle, I can do

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name FROM employees
   WHERE (employee_id, last_name) 
      IN (SELECT employee_id, 'test' FROM employees)
```

How can I do the same with SQL Server ?

Comment: And what does it mean in oracle?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: the same an `IN` with one column does - just with two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

use `Exists` operator

```
SELECT employee_id,
       last_name
FROM   employees a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT employee_id,
               FROM   employees b
               WHERE  a.employee_id = b.employee_id)
       AND a.last_name = 'test'
```

or use `INNER Join`

```
SELECT employee_id,
       last_name
FROM   employees a
       JOIN employees b
         ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
            AND a.last_name = 'test'
```

or Use `In` operator

```
SELECT employee_id,
       last_name
FROM   employees a
WHERE  employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id,
                       FROM   employees b)
       AND a.last_name = 'test'
```

Comment: I think, your solutions may be rewritten simply as `select * from Employees where LastName = 'test'`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - am sure OP would have simplified his problem